# Updating a state variable with a new reference doesn't trigger re-rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a table component for my page in React.
I have a function `loadData()` that makes a request to an api. Using the api result to update the `data` state variable, using a new reference.

The problem here is that React doesn't trigger any re-render for the `data` variable.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const loadData = async () => {
    try {
        ...
        let response_json = await response.json();
        setData(transformData(response_json.items));
        ...
}

const transformData = (data) => {
    if (data === undefined || data === null) {
        return [];
    }
    let new_data = [];
    data.forEach((entry,index) => {
        new_data.push(cloneElement(props.config.table_entry,{data:entry, key:index}, null));
    });
    return new_data;
}
```

I am using this code to change the table's *page*, making a request with parameters like `pageNumber, pageSize, filters`. So even with different data and different reference, still it doesn't trigger re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has challenged me for like one whole morning was that the `data` variable continued to updated on every request made but the webpage never re-rendered.

The answer lies here

```
data.forEach((entry,index) => {
        new_data.push(cloneElement(props.config.table_entry,{data:entry, key:index}, null));
    });
```

in the `transformData` function where it creates a new array of new data, BUT the `key` property of the component never changed because it was the index of its position in the array returned from the server.

Assigning the key to a unique id solved the problem.